# stringbuilder Scala drop duplicate chars

Tags: scala, stringbuilder

```
  class Buffer(s: String) {

  import scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder
  import scala.io.StdIn

  private var buffer: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s)
  private var cursor: Int = 0  // cursor is in between characters
  private var marker: Int = 0  // marker is in between characters
  private var paste: String = ""
  private def end: Int = buffer.length              // the end of the line
  private def lwr: Int = Math.min(marker, cursor)
  private def upr: Int = Math.max(marker, cursor)

  /*
   * Accessor methods to return aspects of the state
   */
  def getCursor: Int = cursor
  def getMarker: Int = marker
  def getString: String = buffer.toString
  def getPaste: String = paste


          /**
       * Delete Duplicate characters.  Within the defined region, for each character,
       * if it occurs once then keep it, but if it occurs multiple times then keep
       * only the first occurrence.  The characters to the left and right of the
       * defined region remain unchanged, but within the defined region the duplicates
       * are removed. This operation does not affect the paste buffer. The cursor is
       * placed finally at the lower end of the defined region and the marker is placed
       * finally at the upper end of the (probably reduced) defined region. For example:
       * 
       *     m i s s i s s i p p i       marker =  1       
       *      ^                 ^        cursor = 10
       *
       * Then perform  sc('a', 'X')
       * 
       *     m i s p i      marker = 1       
       *      ^     ^       cursor = 4
       */
      def dd() 
      {
        var droppedchars: Int = 0;
         for (x <- lwr until upr)
         {
           var c = buffer.charAt(x)
           for (i <- lwr until upr)
           {
             if (buffer.charAt(i) == c)
             {
               buffer.deleteCharAt(i)
               droppedchars += 1

             }
           }
           marker = lwr
           cursor = upr - droppedchars


         }
      }
```

Need some help with this one too, doesn't appear to work
function needs to drop any duplicate chars it finds, move the marker back to the start of the new defined region and the cursor to the end of the new defined region, not asking for somebody to write this for me just guide me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

```
scala> "mississippi".distinct
res22: String = misp
```

Comment: `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<a[ardvar]k> but was a[rdvr]k`
.distinct isn't affecting only the defined region

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment.  "aardvark".distinct yields ardvk on my system.

Comment: distinct affects the whole string, not an its particular region.

Comment: @AlexEvseenko can we use distinct within a given region rather than the whole string?

Comment: For sure, but if the goal is to implement the algorithm it's not a solution, it's a question to TC.

Comment: what about this? `buffer.replace(lwr, upr, getString.slice(lwr, upr).distinct)`

oddly this passes the Junit tests despite not changing the cursor position o.O

Comment: `def uniqueInInterval (w: String, start: Int, stop: Int) = w.take (start-1) + w.substring (start, stop).distinct + w.drop (stop)` would only take uniques in the interval start-stop: `uniqueInInterval ("mississippi", 3, 8)` gives `misippi`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do takes O(n^2) that is not very good from performance perspective...
Imo, a better one solution is use only one loop over the buffer and within it an each character c you should check with a set of characters (declared outside the for-loop):

```
val  chars = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Char]()
```

...

```
for (x <- lwr until upr) {
  var c = buffer.charAt(x)
  if (chars contains c) buffer.deleteCharAt(x) else chars += c
}
cursor = marker + chars.size
```

Comment: from other point, I see one problem in the approach based on mutating the StringBuilder... as soon as you deleteCharAt would be executed, the x becomes incorrect as the overall amount of symbols decreased.
So, the x should incremented only if there is no duplication and becomes unchanged otherwise.

Comment: `object immutable is not a member of package scala`

Comment: Well, it's a package -- and obviously it should be a collection and mutable one as the set is changed over the time. So, correct one package is **scala.collection.mutable** (and you can omit scala package):

val chars = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Char]()